# How to show wishlist block in header magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I would like to able load my 'wishlist' on header block in my magento-1.6 site.
I am using magento1.6.2.0. Now my wishlist is showing up on left side block.
I just changed the reference of wishlist.xml from left to header like

```
 <reference name="header">
        <block type="wishlist/customer_sidebar" name="wishlist_sidebar" as="wishlist"  template="wishlist/sidebar.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

But its not coming 
How can I achieve that..? Which xml file i want to edit ..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All layout XML files are one - that is, they are merged as part of typical rendering.

You need to edit the page/html/header.phtml file and add this bit of code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('wishlist') ?>
```

Before you do any of this though you should read through the articles at the [Official Magento Knowledge Base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base), paying particular attention to the theme hierarchy and developer articles. The time to get theme customizations right is at the beginning of a project.